# How to send List of Expression to Aggregate Function in Spark JAVA API

Tags: java, apache-spark, aggregate, expr

I'm trying to execute below code using Spark JAVA api.

```
sampleDS=sampleDS
    .select(col("column1"),col("column2"),col("price1")col("price2"))
    .groupBy(col("column1"),col("column2"))
    .agg(expr("sum(price1)").as("MainPrice"),expr("sum(price2)").as("ExtPrice"))
    .sort(col("column1"),col("column2"));
```

But this part in the code I want that to be Dynamic,

**`.agg(expr("sum(price1)").as("MainPrice"),expr("sum(price2)").as("ExtPrice"))`**

which means only if a request has *ExtPrice* I need *ExtPrice* to be there , viceversa for *MainPrice*
i.e.
if only *MainPrice* is selected the code should be `.agg(expr("sum(price1)"))`
or when only *ExtPrice* is selected `.agg(expr("sum(price2)"))`
I tried adding the expressions in a List. Something but I got stuck there. 
Can anyone help me here sort this out?